# How do I use Topshelf with a .NET Core 2.1 application?

Tags: .net-core, topshelf

I have an console application on .NET Core 2.1. I have used top-shelf to have it configure it as a windows service.

Has anyone successfully ,installed a .NET Core console application as a windows services using top-shelf.

Any documentation leading to that, would be helpful

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was sucessfully able to install it using [NSSM - the Non-Sucking Service Manager](https://nssm.cc)

Answer (score 2):

I've written a small library that allows you to run `IHostedServices` as a Windows service. The service is configured and run using Topshelf.
https://github.com/erizet/TopshelfHosting

Answer (score 1):

This discussion can be useful: https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf/issues/455

TLDR: There is no stable version for the .NETCore 2.1 and even when it will be available you need to use self-contained application.